# Jmeter - Datastax cassandra driver keeps output DEBUG heartbeat log

Tags: cassandra, jmeter, datastax-java-driver

I'm using jdbc connection configuration to connect to a cassandra cluster.
When my test done, in my terminal it still continue output heartbeat log:

> 18:05:02.306 [cluster1-nio-worker-4] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/10.11.8.103:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
>       18:05:02.307 [cluster1-nio-worker-4] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/10.11.8.103:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
>       18:05:02.312 [cluster1-nio-worker-5] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/10.11.8.103:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
>       18:05:02.314 [cluster1-nio-worker-5] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/10.11.8.103:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
>       18:05:02.575 [cluster1-nio-worker-8] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[cass01.di01.qa.itsonsaas.com/10.11.8.101:9042-3, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
>       18:05:02.577 [cluster1-nio-worker-8] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[cass01.di01.qa.itsonsaas.com/10.11.8.101:9042-3, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
>       .......

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you give more details of your environment (versions, jmeter plugin used, the logic of the test); I tried to replicate the issue with [slowenthal](https://github.com/slowenthal/jmeter-cassandra) Cassandra plugin without success. I'm curious of why the thread is still alive maintaining the connection, have you tried to explicitly close the connection?

Comment: Hi Carlos. My jmeter is 2.10. Use datastax java driver (by putting the jars into $JMTER_HOME/lib/ext). I did try closing the connection explictly like this: java.sql.Connection conn = DataSourceElement.getConnection("cassandara"); conn.close(). "cassandra" is my JDBC Connection Configuration variable